# Trying to print all files smaller than a certain size recursively in C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, file, recursion, size

the issue appears when I try to get all the files smaller than a certain size. In the code bellow, if `size_smaller` is -1, then the code will just print all the files in the directories in a recursive manner (which works). If I set `size_smaller`to a value for which I want to to print the files smaller than `size_smaller` it won't. It will print the smaller valued files in the root directory but not in subdirectories. Hope you understand.

This is the code:

```
void list_recursive(char* path, int size_smaller){
DIR* dir;
struct dirent *dirent;
char * name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LEN);

dir = opendir(path);    
if(dir != NULL){
    if(isRec == 0){
        printf("SUCCESS\n");
    }
    while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if(strcmp(dirent->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dirent->d_name, "..") != 0){
            if(size_smaller == -1){
                sprintf(name, "%s/%s", path, dirent->d_name);
                printf("%s\n", name);
            }
            else if(size_smaller != -1 && dirent->d_type == DT_REG){

                size_t sizeToCheck;

                sprintf(name, "%s/%s", path, dirent->d_name);

                FILE *fp;
                fp = fopen(name, "r");

                fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
                sizeToCheck = ftell(fp);

                printf("\n%zu\n\n", sizeToCheck);

                if(sizeToCheck < size_smaller){
                    printf("%s\n\n", name);
                }

                fclose(fp);
            }
            if(dirent->d_type == DT_DIR){
                isRec = 1;
                list_recursive(name, size_smaller);
            }

        }       
    }

    free(name);
    closedir(dir);  
}
else {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    printf("invalid directory path\n");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The issue was here: `if(size_smaller == -1){
                       sprintf(name, "%s/%s", path, dirent->d_name);
                       printf("%s\n", name);
                  }`

Just had to put `sprintf(name, "%s/%s", path, dirent->d_name);` outside the if.